# Windows Workflow 4.5 Paradigm Questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, workflow-foundation-4

I've been digging into the technical details and implementation of Windows Workflow 4.5 as a beginner and having decent results. My question is more of a "why and when" vs. a "how to" question so bear with me.

I've taken a familiar concept to us all and abstracted the business logic into WF, namely the universal log on process. What I wanted to accomplish is having reusable logic that I can call from an MVC website, a Windows Forms application, etc. and have everything run through the same workflow and I have achieved that.

Now I have 2 conceptual questions as to "when" to apply WF and when to use code.

1 - Take simple validation as an example. I'm trying to login but I've passed an empty user name or password string. Obviously, I want to send a message back to the end-user "UserName Required" and "Password Required", which I've done. Now, the way that I did that is I have a validation class (FluentValidation NuGet package if it matters) but the important thing is I'm doing this in code. So, in WF I call my validation code via an ExecuteMethod and everything works just fine. My question is: Is this the wrong approach with a WF mindset? Should I be doing inline WF "If" Actions/Decisions and building up the validation messages inside of WF directly versus calling out to some chunk of code? I'm asking not just for validation but as a concept we can all relate to but more generally should I be attempting to put anything and everything I can into WF itself or is it better to call custom code? I'm looking more for best practice with reasoning from seasoned Software Architects with WF experience versus someone's opinion if possible.

2 - Picking up a workflow on another machine. So, part of the same login workflow activity requires a service method call. I've written the code and workflow in such a way that the workflow receives an In parameter of ILogOnService which has an interface method "AuthenticateUser". The concrete implementation I'm passing in calls out to an MVC4 Web Api post method, in async, to do a standard Asp.Net membership ValidateUser. Again, should I be calling this Web Api PostAsync from inside the WF workflow? If so, doesn't that tightly-couple my workflow to Asp.Net Membership and my particular service choice. It seems there are ways to get the workflow to a certain point and then resume the process on another machine, e.g. where a service is running, and continue the process but I'm not able to find good examples of attempting that.

Just looking for some guidelines and ideas from the pros at this technology but I will pick the most informative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using C# code to implement details of a workflow. In fact I always tell people that if they are using WF4 with just the standard out of the box activities they are probably doing things wrong. You really need to be creating, or have someone else do it for your, custom activities that model business activities for your business. Now if that means creating an activity that validates a login using the FluentValidation that is perfectly fine. Another time you might build a higher level business activity out of lower level WF4 activities, just combine them as works best in your case.

Calling a service with something like PostAsync can work well if you know the action is short lived and is normally available. However when you get into SOA styles you really want to start using [temporal decoupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) so one service is not dependent on another service being available right away. And when you get into temporal decoupling you really want to be using queues, maybe MSMQ or maybe another similar technology. So in that cas you really want to send a one way message with a response queue and have to workflow go idle and wait for the response message to arrive. This would reload the workfloe, possibly on another machine. Now that might not always be appropriate, for example in your login it would not be much use to grant the login a day later because the membership service was unavailable, but can result in very scalable and fault tolerant systems. Of course there is no free lunch as these systems are very hard to design properly.

Comment: The custom activities make sense. I was already considering a simple WebApiActivity for instance. The parameters would be something like Baseurl, Controller, Action. That would seem to lean towards a proper decoupled architecture that's easily translated into queues or even simple "take offline" operations. No we can't have a user logged in a week later hehe but your point is valid. The queue here could be replaced with a LoadBalancerActivity picking from 5 services. How would you approach passing the config info for each elegantly without fighting WF or creating activity In parameter bloat?

Comment: I'm also assuming that by creating my LogOnActivity I'll be able to later reuse that as a custom activity. Meaning, I have in my head, that when I "zoom-out" architecturally-speaking I will have a higher level activity that I could use to ensure a user is either logged in already (authenticated) -or- gets routed to the LogOnActivity which would be a nice workflow to call inside the BaseController OnActionExecuting, etc. Thanks for your time here, I know it's a nebulous question.

Comment: They started something along those line. Check [HttpWorkflowService](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebAPIWorkflow). Check source code also. WF on codeplex used to be where MS released their WF activities/code before goes public (and integrated with some framework version). It seems somehow stopped. [Ron Jacobs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/) was the "leader" but unfortunately  [he isn't well](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2013/01/10/my-last-post.aspx).